# InDesign - What are ‘safe’ A5 book settings for UK/US Printers and Amazon KDP?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I’m looking to write a book. It will include graphics to the edge.

I am unsure on the `Adobe InDesign` Settings to use (page size, trim, bleed + slug, margins etc).

Most sites seem to state A5 trim size as [21cm x 14.8cm](https://digital.imprint.co.uk/paperback-book-size/). Measuring other authors books in my bookshelf, this seems to match reality (in the UK)

However, [Amazon KDP](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GVBQ3CMEQW3W2VL6)  doesn’t offer this as a size. The closest trim size is  8.25" x 6" (20.96 x 15.24 cm).

I’d like the option of using Amazon if I can’t find a publisher for the book . These settings seem so fundamental to everything, I don’t want to have to re-format the entire book to look correctly aligned if I go the self publish route.

What sizes would enable compatibility with with both types please?

Comment: I think you might be in bad luck. It seems that Amazon never bothered to offer dimensions after DIN. The german version is also just a literal translation of the american, (inlcuding the statement about  6" x 9" being the US' most common trim size) 
Did you use Indesign? Maybe you can just add an alternative layout and leave the type area as it is (so that the text won't change) and just move it so that it looks good with the other measurements.